# When Setting up Cypress 'configFile is invalid'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, cypress

The error I get is:

> Your configFile is invalid: `/Users/mic/Desktop/Projects/MCAT/client/cypress.config.ts`

I am simply trying to install cypress on to my project and am having this problem from the get go. I have tried delete and reinstalling package files. I've also tried manipulating tsconfig.json in multiple ways.

[image: Cypress and file tree]

[image: package.json]

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant code in your question instead of providing screenshots of it.

Answer (score 6):

Reinstalling by itself will not help you, Cypress sees the old (invalid) config and does not generate the file on the second install.

You must remove the `cypress.config.ts` file, delete the cypress folder, then reinstall Cypress.

On opening, Cypress will then create a correct `cypress.config.ts` for you.

Make sure you also have installed typescript before you open Cypress, as it needs to recognize that you want to use typescript.